# substr() not working

Tags: php, string

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("get_a_class");
$rightHeader = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM scalena_news ORDER BY date DESC");
?>

<div id="slider">
    <ul>
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rightHeader)){?>
        <li>
             <span class="Text-3">
                <?php echo substr($row['description'],0,50); ?>
             </span>
        </li> 
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But I don't get anything. When I remove `substr()` it displays the whole text fine!

Comment: if 'description' contains html characters, you may not see the string, I mean, if you use an editor like tinymce there you can have some html code, whoy don't you try to get 250 char from the text, for any problem you can see this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: What is the content of `$row['description']`? So far, the code looks fine.

Comment: It also will not display if it data contains a lot of whitespace at the start. Put a `trim()` around the `$row['description']` to make sure this is removed.

Comment: no it doesn't contain any html characters.... its simply a text stored in the DB

Comment: $row['description'] = text records

Comment: no white spaces too :( i had checked it again n again

Comment: This might be stupid, but try to increase the number step by step (by 10 or so) and see what happens...

Comment: If possible, can you provide us with a `var_dump($row['description']);`

Comment: It seems we cannot do much. Your code looks good, so it must be something with the content. How about reproducing your problem on a site such as http://codepad.org or http://ideone.com/ ?

Comment: "some text" is the real text or you didn't show the real text? because string(574) means your text is 574 characters long, which is strange.

Comment: no no its just wat i rite cuz i couldnt provide that much long text over here

Comment: Ok different approach. Try it without the html/css. (Maybe bad styles actually hiding the text)

Comment: exactly !!! thats was some Css issue :) thank you very very much you all :)

Comment: @Atif Added as an answer so you can accept and close the question :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
  <div id="slider">
  <ul>
  <?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rightHeader)){
  echo '<li><span class="Text-3">'.htmlentities(substr($row['description'],0,50)).'</span></li>';
  } 
  ?>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Atif check out the revision.

Comment: its not showing up mannn !! but wat issue can it be :( why not it returns only the desire code :(

Comment: How about <?php var_dump($row['description']); ?> as Leigh said?

Comment: i say again: when i do not use the substr function it shows me all the text but when i apply this function then it doesnt show even a single word

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc($rightHeader)` only returns **one** row from the result set. Hence your foreach loop does not really work.

Comment: Are you sure there is no incomplete html tags in that $row['description'] ? how about: htmlentities($row['description']) ?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing all CSS from your code and trying again, it's possible that the output is being generated, but is somehow being hidden.

You can verify by showing the source of the page, and seeing if your text is actually present or not.

Answer (score 0):

Something to try :

```
... echo htmlentities(substr(trim($row['description']), 0, 50)); ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
substr(htmlentities($row['description']),0,50)
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are trying to create summary text....

Please try and use this function

```
function create_summary($cont,$num){


        $text = strip_tags($cont);

        if(strlen($text) > $num){

            $endpos = strpos($text,' ',$num);
            $dots = '...';
            if(!$endpos){
                $endpos = strlen($text);
                $dots = '';
            }

        }else{
            $endpos = strlen($text);
                        $dots ='';
        }                   
        return substr($text,0,$endpos).$dots;
    }
```

Comment: it seems to complex for me to understand this code :( as i m not much expert ... so will u plz explain a lil what this code do ?

Comment: $cont is the text that you want to make summary, $num is the number to restrict the text length..... inside function first it will strip all the html tags in the $cont. then it will check whether the $cont length is greater that the restrict $num.. if so then it will reduce the text to the $num length and add "..." at the end of the text.... if the text is shorter then it will return the original text without "..." all you got to do is paste this function in your php file and echo create_summary($row['description'],50) which will give you what you are looking for.....